# find_peaks() put the peaks correct, but squeezed the plot left benear

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to detect peaks in a curve via scipy library and it's function find_peaks().
If I plot the curve without find_peaks()-function in my script it's plotted as expected.
But if I'm using find_peaks() function in my script the plot shows this unexpected behaviour.
Any idea what's going wrong in here is appreciated.
Thx a lot.

If I plot the curve without find_peaks()-function it's plotted as expected:

[image: normal plot]

But if I'm using find_peaks() function the plot shows this unexpected behaviour:

[image: squeezed plot]

I used this source code as the squeezed plot was shown:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks


"""Read the file

"""
path = '../data/accelerometer/Wrist-Accelerometer-X-Axis-UpDown.csv'


"""Define the variables

"""
w = data['elapsed (s)']
x = data['x-axis (g)']


"""Plot the data

"""
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 4))


ax1.plot(w, x, marker='.')
ax1.set_title('UpDown movement: Behaviour of x-axis')
ax1.set_xlabel('$Datapoints$')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax1.set_ylabel('$Acceleration \n on x-axis (g)$')
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.AutoLocator())
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, -2, 0, prominence=1, distance=1)
ax1.plot(peaks, x[peaks], 'x', markersize=8)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps the plot call should be `ax1.plot(w[peaks], x[peaks], 'x', markersize=8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That answered my question: I stacked them beneath due to missing dimension.

- Original line in the code:

```py
ax1.plot(peaks, x[peaks], 'x', markersize=8)
```

- Correct line in the code:

```py
ax1.plot(w[peaks], x[peaks], 'x', markersize=8)
```

- Result:

[image: Expected = Given]